# iOS AES Encryption with Vulnerability: Signed Memory Arithmetic

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption, aes

I'm using AES encryption to encrypt / decrypt user's info in my app.
This is the code I'm using:
https://gist.github.com/matsuda/9204276
Everything works just fine.
But the code got scanned for security vulnerability recently and there's an issue that got flagged.

The vulnerability: 
Signed Memory Arithmetic
Description: 
    The software reads or writes to a buffer using an index or pointer that references a memory location after the end of the buffer.

Line 39-40 of `NSData+AES.m` of the code in the above link is where it got highlighted
    `size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;`
    `void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);`

I'm not sure what I should do.
The buffer size is calculated with dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128 just before allocation so the length should be okay?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Some of the problems with the code are using strings for the iv and key, the key is not extended with a function such as PBKDF2, using ECB mode even when an iv is supplied, null padding the key and iv. If you need to use 3rd party code use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor).

Comment: Since there's no reading or writing to the buffer there, it seems like the line numbers are wrong.